# $|f (z)|$ can reach its minimum value at an interior point when the minimum value is zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Show that $|f (z)|$ can reach its minimum value at an interior point when the minimum value is zero.

Can someone provide any method to do this?

I have proved the fact $|f (z)|$ has a minimum value $m$ in $R$ which occurs on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior.

Comment: Don't you just need an example? How about $f(z)=z$ on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Your proof is wrong. That statement that $f$ can only achieve a minimum $m$ in $R$ on the boundary is only true if $m > 0$.